# Не устанавливается OpenVPN Connect

Tags: windows, windows-10

Нужна помощь по установке OpenVPN Connect 3.1. Не могу установить, ибо появляется следующая ошибка после копирования файлов:

[image: Скриншот с ошибкой]

Я пробовал отключать антивирусную программу 360 Total Security, но это не помогло. Сам файл установки имеет расширение **.msi**

Comment: ты запускал из под администратора?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть сообщения в системных журналах. Для этого в командной строке, запущенной от имени администратора, введите "eventvwr.msc", а в дереве вариантов выберите "Журналы Windows - Установка".

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev MSI файл не запускается из под администратора. Но пробовал запустить cmd.exe в режиме администратора и оттуда запустить сам файл

Comment: @R0bur в "Установка" ничего нет, а вот в "Приложение" есть ошибка MsiExec.exe KERNELBASE.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Возможно, инсталлятор msi не соответствует архитектуре операционной системы (32/64 бит). 
2) Версия 3.1 является "тестовой", тогда как стабильная версия продукта - 2.7.

*Прошу прощения за публикацию "ответа", а не комментария. Для последнего не хватает баллов репутации.*

Comment: У меня Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, до этого была Windows 8.1 и там OpenVPN Connect 3.1 работал стабильно. Версия 2.7 у меня устанавливается, но не работает